# Best User friendly button label for "canceling the getting information request"

Tags: buttons, user-research, labels

I have a form which populates automatically by getting information from server, and by the time its polling the information. I am showing a loader.

But a user can anytime Cancel the polling request. So, I have to add a button for that canceling request next to Loader.

Can you please suggest what should be the "Label" for button, which cancel the polling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've used something like this in an app...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDcqCa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It makes it clear what you are loading and concisely describes what you're cancelling if you choose to click the link. Because it's not a typical action, we put that as a "link" as oppose to a physical button.

You can easily translate this to a progress bar like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f48AH2.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I actually implemented same thing... now it confirms it does make correct sense!! Thanks once again!!!

Comment: Hi Can you please also look into my question "http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57773/best-position-and-label-for-buttons-on-web-page", which is similar to my this question???

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the screenshot of what I did! If you think anything can be done to make it better... please suggest!!! Thanks!