# Best position and labels for buttons on an order creation page

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, labels, wireframe, position

I have a "create order" interface which already includes several buttons. Please have a look at the screenshot below:

![enter image description here][1]

**My Question:**

1. I need to add a new button ("Add New Item") which should be visible and accessible to the user at all times, even if they have scrolled down the page. Where should this button be?;
2. I need to change the position of the "Cancel" link to make it clear that all the package details which are loading will be canceled. Can you suggest a better position and label for this?

So far I have considered adding these two buttons at the end in a 'static' position, so even if the user scrolls the window these buttons will still be accessible. Please screenshot the screen below.

![enter image description here][2]

{removed the images for Data Privacy Reason}

Comment: What is the packaging loading behaviour like? Say you need to load 3 packages. Does it first fetch package 1, immediately display that while it's loading package 2 or does it wait until it has fetched everything before displaying it all at once? If it loads sequentially, where do these items show up? At the bottom table or does it go into table above as the last row?

Comment: Is it important to short circuit a process such as loading a package? It appears that once a package is loaded, like the rows above, you can delete it.

If loading a package is a reversible action, and is non-destructive to the order, why not let the user just load it, then decide if they want to cancel. Otherwise you have two interactions: delete a detail once it's been loaded, or abort a process. Either one gets you the same end result, at least it appears that way.

If you can provide more context, that would be useful.

Comment: your image is gone ?!

Answer (score 1):

I would use two columns. On the left column, users scroll down the orders, and take order-specific actions. On the right column, you have the static buttons that do actions that are not order-specific (like add new order or clear all orders), and this column stays in the same position as the user scrolls down the page.

You can also have a "following" section on the top (or bottom) of the page that stays in the same position while the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

I can't upvote yet but I would be happy as a user with either top left or category tabs. so imagine two upvotes, one on each.

if it didn't follow me, I'd would on android or anything not apple appreciate a "tap top to go to top" option (apple) and also a "tap bottom of screen to return /to where you were when you tapped " top."

I do a fair bit of online shopping and am online on mobile almost daily, usually for at least 8 hrs and often far more. right now my life is online, with a dash of reluctant offline.

a huge annoyance, in browsing lists or products (ordering or not) is how, when you choose an item to view or get or review, you go back to the start. always. I've abandoned many large lists (of all kinds, on all devices that go online) just because of how achingly slow it becomes and how hard it is to find where you were if the list is really large.

I've also more than a few times abandoned a purchase or a promising article because of something covering the content or a function butten that is hard to dismiss or recurs instantly and infinitely. related. just wanted to out that out there for designers to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I think the top left would be the best position to put these buttons. They are quite easy to miss down at the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to categorize your actions in groups like 'Primary', 'secondary' actions. 
Primary actions - 'Create Order' and 'Add new item'
Secondary action - 'Cancel'

Think about 'Accordance' of these action buttons on the basis of primary and secondary. (as shown in image below)

You can also use 'Floating' buttons or FAB for 'Add New Item'.

Let me know if you agree with my response.

[image]